# Mapping with IO actions in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, io

I have a function that takes two filenames, and reads the contents of those two files into `String`s, and then returns if they match or not. Here's the function:

```
f :: String -> String -> IO Bool
f fileName1 fileName2 = do
        str1 <- readFile fileName1
        str2 <- readFile fileName2
        return (str1 == str2)
```

And if I use it like this from inside `main`:

```
main = do
        res <- f "A.txt" "B.txt"
        print res
```

It works and prints either `True` or `False`. What I want to do is, apply this function `f` to a list (of tuples) of filenames. For something like:

```
[("a.txt", "b.txt"), ("c.txt", "d.txt")]
```

(Assume that `a.txt` and `b.txt` have the same content and `c.txt` and `d.txt` are different).

I want to transform it (the list of file names) into a `Bool` list like: `[True, False]`. I tried using `mapM`, but that doesn't appear to map anything (when I print the list after using `mapM`, it prints the same list of tuples).

So my question is: What am I doing wrong, and how can I get a list of `Bool`s like I mentioned above?

Please go easy on me as I'm still quite new to Haskell and functional programming :)

Comment: What does your `mapM` code look like?

Comment: @DavidYoung `mapM (\(a, b) -> f a b) lst`. `lst` is the list of tuples I posted above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function `f'` which does what you describe.

```
f' :: [(String,String)] -> IO [Bool]
f' = mapM $ uncurry f
```

Let me know if something is unclear! And, just to be clear, here is how you run it:

```
main = do
        res <- f' [("a.txt", "b.txt"), ("c.txt", "d.txt")]
        print res
```

#### EDIT

The function is in pointfree form, so it is equivalent to `f' lst = mapM (uncurry f) lst`. `mapM` essentially maps each element of `lst` using `f` as the function, and pushes the `IO` to the outside of the list.

`uncurry` just takes a function of the form `a -> b -> c` and transforms it into one `(a,b) -> c`, which is what we want since you have a list of tuples.

Comment: It worked! Thanks :) But can you please explain a bit about the use of `uncurry`? And what exactly is going on behind it and `mapM`?

Comment: Got it :) Thanks a lot again, for the answer _and_ the explanation. I wasn't sure how `mapM` and `uncurry` worked, now okay though.